# Error scraping link from site using a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get matches from some text using regex, but the code fails to yield any results.

The text contains

```
action="https://www.localhost.com/en/account?dwcont=C338711466"
```

My code is

```cs
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.localhost.com/en/account");
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = this.cookieJar;
string text2;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
   string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim().ToString();
   string[] array = (from Match match in Regex.Matches(text, "\"https://www.localhost.com/en/account?dwcont=(.+?)\"")
                     select match.Groups[1].Value).ToArray<string>();
   text2 = array[0];
}

MessageBox.Show(text2);
```

I get error in array:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

Is there a solution for it?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't make sense! also put the error message you getting

Comment: `var array = Regex.Matches(text, "\"https://www\\.localhost\\.com/en/account\\?dwcont=([^\"]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);` and then `text2 = array.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: thanks your answer solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get your `array` using

```
var array = Regex.Matches(text, "\"https://www\\.localhost\\.com/en/account\\?dwcont=([^\"]+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Then, get the first match using

```
text2 = array.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note you need to escape literal `.` and `?` symbols in the regex pattern, and since you are using a regular string literal you should use double backslashes to create regex escapes.

You got the `Index was outside the bounds of the array` error because your regex failed to extract any match and `array[0]` was trying to access a `null` value.

Comment: is there a site to do this regex here this <input type="hidden" name="dwfrm_login_securekey" value="46683728" />

Comment: @AlholiHamed What do you mean?

Comment: i mean is there a site to do the regex online like this site for php https://phpliveregex.com this regex doesn't work    <input type="hidden" name="dwfrm_login_securekey" value="46683728" />

Comment: @AlholiHamed If you mean a .NET regex compatible Web site, you may use regexhero.net or regexstorm.net. I do not understand what does not work for you. The current regex is compatible with any non-POSIX regex flavor. You can even test it at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vts10C/1) that does not support .NET regex.

Comment: i make this "dwfrm_login_securekey" value="46683728" />   like this but it still  doesn't work  "\"dwfrm_login_securekey\" value=\"(.*)\"/>/"

Comment: @AlholiHamed The regex string is `"dwfrm_login_securekey" value="([^"]*)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vts10C/2). The string literal in C# is `"\"dwfrm_login_securekey\" value=\"([^\"]*)"`